# how to access the windows program installed uisng wine?

Tags: wine

How to access the windows programs installed using wine on ubuntu 12.04. dash did not show as well as there was no desktop icon. any ideas

Comment: have you tried searching the app name from the dash?

Answer (score 0):

After Installing Wine,you are able to install any windows programer running .exe. If you have proper installed Windows program than you can find it in Dash.

Comment: thanx, i am able to access the pdf-xchage view but another program (DNAstar - bioinformatic tool)icon is present in dash but does not open.

Comment: I have noticed that not all the Windows programs run well under Linux, even if you have Wine installed. Some of them have bugs, others freeze and others won't start at all. Seem to me that you case falls in the last category.